# Naming dimensions of a chunk of earth

Tags: geography, terminology

Norway would fit in a bounding box of 500x1600x3 km, where 500 km is east-west, 1600 is north-south, and 3 km is up-down. What do you call these dimensions?

When speaking about furniture, you use width, depth, and height, but depth is confusing, because in this context it would be the opposite of height.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is better suited to [English Language and Usage SE](https://english.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Maybe he furniture people are using the terms incorrectly. In this situation I've always used length instead of depth. Depth can sometimes be used to mean how far back does something go, in terms of extent. On other occasions I've seen breadth be used instead of width. Breadth coming from the word broad: how broad is something, or how wide is it. In the situation you mention, I 'd use length, width & height (or elevation).